# use a ruby gem in development for rails and test method exposure

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems

I have a simple task I can accomplish with a single ruby script but I want to learn how to make a gem and maybe even use it in a rails app; best way always seems to be a practical application with a contrived representation.  The end goal is to parse a csv file, exclude some lines based on a filter (regexp match), and output whats left; whats shown here is a simple hello world to help wrap my brain around this.  I'm stuck on 2 things.

1. Am I running my code as a work in progress properly?  IF for example this was a simple script I would just enter terminal and run "ruby list_cleaner.rb" and it would execute... but now I have this gem file structure and I'm unsure which file I should call?  When I call my top level gem/gem_name.rb script nothing happens (as I would expect since all I do in that file is autoload other files).  When I call the first autoloaded file (base.rb) it works, but is that how I should run this thing while WIP?
2. how do I test if methods from one module or class in another file are accessible by another?  assert_kind? assert_nil?  I couldn't seem to figure it out!  So I defined a method 'hello' in my 'contraints.rb' file, included that and called 'hello' in base.rb.  When running base.rb script I get a `uninitialized constant ListCleaner::Constraints (NameError)`.  I would like to figure out how to test this and obviously fix it!

Some very simple hello world examples and file structure are below.

top level directory & gem name is "list_cleaner"

```
#list_cleaner/lib/list_cleaner.rb
module ListCleaner
    autoload :Base, 'list_cleaner/base'
    autoload :Constraints, 'list_cleaner/constraints'
end

#list_cleaner/lib/base.rb
module ListCleaner
    class Base
        include ListCleaner::Constraints
        hello #a method from the constraints rb auto loaded and included right?
    end
end

#list_cleaner/lib/constraints.rb
module ListCleaner
    class Constraints #long term this will be filled with 'filter' methods
      def hello
        puts('hello world')
      end

    end
end

#list_cleaner/test/list_cleaner_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class ListCleanerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "truth" do
    assert_kind_of Module, ListCleaner
  end
  test "constrains exposed to Base?" do 
    assert_kind_of constraints, base, 'msg' #is constraints part of base?
  end
end
```

I'm reading / working through "crafting rails application" by Jose Valim & using some Internet guides; just can't seem to apply some fundamental workings on my own.  With this example I'm really just attempting to figure out how I can call a method in one file (module, class, or whatever is best?) from another file (again, module, class, whatever is best?), and test it.  So I not only want to make all of it work but test that it will work with unit tests and calling it from terminal to see it perform (in this case output "hello world").

Thanks for any direction you can offer, I appreciate it!

Comment: Although not necessary an answer, I consider it bad taste to create the same module in different files. Either break it up into different modules names, or put it all into one file.

Comment: The book im working off of does that alot but your comment makes sense and is helpful... thanks ill break it up.

Comment: I'm curious, which book are you working off of? I suspect they did that to make things simple, at the cost of enforcing bad practices.

Comment: crafting rails applications by jose valim

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a lot all at once.

This code is simpler and shows how to write a test for a module:

```
#foo/lib/hi.rb
module Hi

  def hi
    puts "hello"
  end

end

#foo/test/hello_test.rb
class HelloTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  class X
    include Hi
  end

  test "says hello" do
    assert_equal X.new.hi, "hello"
  end

end
```

To run the test using just plain ruby:

```
ruby -Ilib -Itest test/*.rb
```

Are you able to run this successfully?

Comment: Returned an error.  `<class:X>': uninitialized constant ListCleanerTest::X::Hi (NameError).  I've checked a few times for errors on my end, I'll keep looking and researching.  Your response is helpful, you taught me that instead of testing for the existence of a method in a class I test for the response of the method when called... That makes sense... Thanks!

Comment: I started again with "rails plugin new hi"... and my test did something different (which confuses me).  Still failed... "<nil> expected but was <"hello">.

Comment: Glad to help. To make it even simpler, try to get your code running as just Ruby code, not as a Rails plugin. Instead of the "test" keyword, use Ruby Minitest e.g. "def test_says_hello".